# Extract and transform data at the same time

Tags: xml, xslt

Here is my XML :

```
<p>
  <t>bla bla bla <XX>bla<REG /> bla</XX> bla</t>
  <t>bli bli bli <XX>bli bli</XX> bli</t>
  <t>blo <REG /> blo blo <XX>blo blo <REG /></XX></t>
</p>
```

I want to extract the text contained into XX and replace REG by a slash - at the same time (in order to have bla / bla - example for first line).

I can do both one at a time, but I wasn't able to apply both rules to my tag. Is it possible with XSLT 1.0?

Here are my XSLT rules (very basic) :

```
<xsl:template match="REG">
  <xsl:text> / </xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XX">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

I tried to replace  by a string (a slash) using substring-before and substring-after, but it doesn't work with tags.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have samples in the data where other things happen. you have an "XX" element with no REG, you have a "t" element with a "REG" and no "XX". You should fully explain what you wish as input and output from your sample or the other occurrences that do not match your description may be handled wrong in any answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem lies with the template that matches **XX**. Looking a particular example of an **XX** node in your document, for example

```
<XX>bla<REG /> bla</XX>
```

Then this **XX** element actually has three child nodes; a text node "blah", the **REG** element, and another text node " blah". So, you should think of **XX** of just having single content. Doing **xsl:value-of** on it, simply concatenates all descendant text nodes within it.

What you need to do is replace your current template that matches **XX** with two templates.

The first will match **XX** as currently, but simply pass processing onto its child elements (i.e XX won't be output). The second template will specifically match child text nodes of **XX** elements, where you can then output the text

Try these two templates instead

```
<xsl:template match="XX">
  <xsl:apply-templates />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="XX/text()">
  <xsl:value-of select="normalize-space(.)"/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Hi Tim, that works perfectly ! Thanks for your time and your very informative comment :)